# Linear Algebra - calculate basis of U and W.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this two groups.

$U=\{(x,y,z,t)\in R^4 | y+z+t=0\}$

$W = \{(x,y,z,t) \in R^4 | x+y=0$ and $z=2t\}$

I need to find a basis for $U \cap W$.

This is what I did :

First of all I get basis for $U$ and $W$.

$U \in R^4$, and $p(U) = dimU = 3$

$$B_u = sp\{(0,1,-1,0),(1,0,0,0),(0,-1,0,1)\}$$

$W \in R^4$ and $p(W) = dimW = 2$
$$B_w= sp\{(0,0,1,2),(1,-1,0,0)\}$$

Therefore :

$$B_u=B_w$$
$$B_u-B_w=0$$
$$\lambda_1(0,0,-1,0)+\lambda_2(1,0,0,0)+\lambda_3 (0,-1,0,1)-\lambda_4(0,0,1,2)-\lambda_5(1,-1,0,0)=0$$
$$\lambda_1(0,0,-1,0)+\lambda_2(1,0,0,0)+\lambda_3 (0,-1,0,1)+\lambda_4(0,0,-1,-2)+\lambda_5(-1,+1,0,0)=0$$

EDIT:

Results for matrix :

$$\lambda_1=-0.5x_5$$
$$\lambda_2=x_5$$
$$\lambda_3=x_5$$
$$\lambda_4=0.5x_5$$
$$\lambda_5=arbitrary$$

Using $W$ to calculate :

$$-0.5 \lambda_5(0,0,1,2) + \lambda_5(1,-1,0,0)=\lambda_5(1,-1,-0.5,-1)$$

Therefore

$$Sp\{(1,-1,0.5,-1)\} = Base for $U \cap W$$

also I'll be glad to know why in when calculating $U \cap W$ I need to put the vector as columns and not as rows.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^4$ is a $4$-dimensional space. If you impose only one linear condition, $y+z+t=0,$ you get a $3$-dimensional space. That is, $U$ is $3$-dimensional. Anyway, to get a basis for the intersection the best way is to consider all equations together.

Comment: @mfl You'r right, edited, can you take alook please?

Comment: You are right with the dimensions of $U$ and $W.$ Consider the equations $y+z+t=0,x+y=0,z=2t$ to get the intersection of both vector subspaces. If you follow your process you have $5$ unknowns involved.

Comment: I keep the process, put the vectors using colums and then grading the matrix I get that the $dimU \cap W = 4$ and also that the linear system has infinitely solutions.

Comment: Note that $U$ has dimension three and $W$ has dimension two. So, $U\cap W$ has at most dimension two. Since you have four unknowns and three equations try to write the solution in terms of one of the unknowns, say $t.$ You should get a $1$-dimensional space.

Comment: I edited, that's what you mean?

Comment: @mfl I'll wait, thank you for your help.

Comment: The difference between our solutions is a typo in your base $B_W.$ Note that the first vector of your basis should read $(0,0,2,1).$ Now you can compare both methods, but, in my opinion, the best way is to work directly with the equations defining the vector subspaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vectors in $U\cap W$ are those that satisfy

$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} y+z+t & = 0\\ x+y & = 0 \\ z-2t & = & 0\end{array}\right. \implies \left\{\begin{array}{rcl} y+z & = -t\\ x+y & = 0 \\ z & = & 2t\end{array}\right.\implies \left\{\begin{array}{rcl} x& = & 3t\\ y & = &  -3t\\ z & = & 2t \end{array}\right.$$

That is, they can be written as $(3t,-3t,2t,t)=t(3,-3,2,1),t\in\mathbb{R}.$ So $\{(3,-3,2,1)\}$ is a basis for the intersection.